# Selenium Webdriver - JAVA: Selecting item from a gird view

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Selenium Webdriver - JAVA:**

How to select a specific item from gird view table,like shown in the below snapshot:
[image: Table View]

**HTML code:**

```html
<div id="pnlTreeHeadNode" class="x-panel" style="width: 764px;">
   <div class="x-panel-bwrap" id="ext-gen193">
      <div class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-noheader" id="ext-gen194" style="height: 228px; width: 762px;">
         <div id="TreeOSView" class=" x-panel x-tree">
            <div class="x-panel-bwrap" id="ext-gen455">
               <div class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-noheader" id="ext-gen456" style="overflow: auto; position: relative; height: 228px;">
                  <ul class="x-tree-root-ct x-tree-lines" id="ext-gen457">
                     <li class="x-tree-node">
                        <div ext:tree-node-id="0" class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable x-tree-node-expanded x-tree-selected" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-end-minus"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon btn-main-style dt-btn-people" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Root Node</span></a></div>
                        <ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="">
                           <li class="x-tree-node">
                              <div ext:tree-node-id="1" class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable x-tree-node-collapsed" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-plus"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon btn-main-style dt-btn-people" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Administration  | General Manager | Jihad</span></a></div>
                              <ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul>
                           </li>
                           <li class="x-tree-node">
                              <div ext:tree-node-id="1120" class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable x-tree-node-collapsed x-tree-node-over" unselectable="on"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-icon"></span><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-end-plus"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-tree-node-icon btn-main-style dt-btn-people" unselectable="on"><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on">Department 22 | Funtion 22 | user 23</span></a></div>
                              <ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"></ul>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <input type="hidden" size="20" autocomplete="off" id="TreeOSView_SM" name="TreeOSView_SM" class=" x-form-hidden x-form-field" value="{&quot;nodeID&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Root Node&quot;,&quot;path&quot;:&quot;/0&quot;,&quot;attributes&quot;:{&quot;nodeType&quot;:&quot;async&quot;}}"><input type="hidden" size="20" autocomplete="off" id="TreeOSView_CheckNodes" name="TreeOSView_CheckNodes" class=" x-form-hidden x-form-field" value="">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I have tried the below code but it did not work:By locAllRows = By.xpath(".//*[contains(@class,'x-grid3-body')]//*[contains(@class,'x-grid3-row')]");

Comment: For First element in the list, xpath is - `//*[@id="ext-gen457"]/li/ul/li[1]/div/a/span`. For Second element in the list, xpath is - `//*[@id="ext-gen457"]/li/ul/li[2]/div/a/span` . Lets see if it works.

Comment: Thank you @ka These are dynamic IDS it is not recommended to use dynamic ID

Comment: Please clear the Requirement and Paste your code

Comment: @AhmadOdeh - Some part of the id must be static, we can use that part. Just check which part is static.

Comment: Not working, I have recvied the below message upon using the xPath you have provided:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <span unselectable="on">...</span> is not clickable

Comment: Dears I think we need a for loop here to deal with the table, can anyone help me in that

Answer (score 0):

To identify level 1/root node, you can try:

```
//ul[@class='x-tree-root-ct x-tree-lines']/li/div/a[@class='x-tree-node-anchor']
```

and to identify the level 2 list items, you can try:

```
//ul[@class='x-tree-node-ct']//a[@class='x-tree-node-anchor']
```